# How to change the image of a group chat in microsoft teams

Tags: macos, microsoft-teams

I did not find a way to change the image of a group chat (NOT a team) in microsoft teams under Chat. If I click on the edit pencil, I can only change the name of the group.

MacOS: 12.0.1

[image: group chat image]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! If you can give more detail on what you have tried so far, we may be able to help you faster. I personally think that the problem will be somewhere with the priviledges you need to change the icon.

Comment: The image is a montage of the avatars of the members of the chat, so if none of the users have an image assigned to their Teams account, the default is what you see. You can't specify a custom image on a group chat.

Comment: @spikey_richie Thanks, that clears it up.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As [@spikey_richie stated in a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1693206/how-to-change-the-image-of-a-group-chat-in-microsoft-teams/1730656#comment2603976_1693206), the image is a montage of the avatars of the members of the chat.

So if none of the users have an image assigned to their Teams account, the default is what you see. You can't specify a custom image on a group chat.

Comment: Adding this feature will be a real breakthrough in the world of technology

Comment: Microsoft is so slow to add common chat app features. At least this feature is planned (no update for 7 months though. status set March 2023): https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/411c5e22-7ebd-ed11-83ff-000d3a1ab7d1